# App searches in wrong directory

Tags: sd-card, internal-storage, music

I just installed [DroidID3Tagger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.booleancorp), however it just searches for my music files in `/mnt/sdcard`, my music however is in `/mnt/emmc`.

Is there anything I can do instead of moving the files?

I'm using CM9 Nightly on a SGS1 with Icy Glitch Kernel. (for some reason the Kernel swapped sdcard and emmc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to @Zuul's comment below his answer, usage of the `ln -sf /mnt/emmc /mnt/sdcard` is not the appropriate way of dealing with it, because it's a soft-link and forcing it that way, can lead to some mis-behaviour of apps who are relying on the SDCard's mount point, by way of refusing to work with it, Play Store can fail in this regard.

The best solution is to use this:

By using `busybox`, explicitly bind the mount point to make `/mnt/emmc` behave exactly like a SDCard, i.e:

`/system/xbin/busybox mount -o bind /mnt/emmc /mnt/sdcard`

Which will show up as a mount point in the proper way, if this was a soft-link it would end up like this -

```
/mnt/sdcard -> /mnt/emmc
```

Google Play store, as I mentioned has an internal checking mechanism to see if the directory is not a link (it will return a error of -22 IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

This app reads files from the device internal storage located at `/mnt/sdcard`, not from the external storage or any other location.

Since the app was last updated on March 4 2011, I don't think this will get fixed.

---

However, if you have root on your device, you can create a soft link from one location to another thus tricking the app.

The command is used like this:

```
ln -sf {target-filename} {symbolic-filename}
```

So you should execute:

```
ln -sf /mnt/emmc /mnt/sdcard
```

When the app accesses the `/mnt/sdcard` the system will give it the contents of `/mnt/emmc`.

Comment: Just for clarification it does use /mnt/sdcard, but in my case it's my external SD. /mnt/emmc is my internal SD. (Something got messed up when I installed the Icy Glitch Kernel)                                                                    I tried this code in "Virtual Terminal", i get the error message "link failed No such file or directory".

Comment: hmmm... maybe `ln` is not the appropriate way to deal with it - perhaps using `busybox` as in `/system/xbin/busybox mount -o bind /mnt/emmc /mnt/sdcard` ?

Comment: Yes, that worked ;) I don't use the app anymore but it might come in handy on other things aswell

Comment: @wayback What end up solving the issue, the soft link or the mount?

Comment: @Zuul The busybox/mount solved it

Comment: @t0mm13b Your attention is needed here. Your comment solved the issue, perhaps moving it to an answer, thus allowing the OP to accept it and close this problem.

Comment: @wayback Thank you for the feed back, lets wait for t0mm13b's answer.